# JavaScript Sort by Date on table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Hi I cannot get sort function working on date. It changes order of the rows but it doesn't sort properly and dates are all over the place.

I would like upcoming events to future events.

See my code below.

```js
$('tr.Entries').sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(jQuery(a).find('td.event-date > a').text()).getTime() < 
    new Date(jQuery(b).find('td.event-date > a').text()).getTime() 
}).appendTo('tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="event clearfix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Event</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Ticket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">25/08/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Live N Local Winter Music Festival</a> 
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Pause Bar, Balaclava</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">15/04/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Reggae, Seggae &amp; Sega Night</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Bar Open, Fitzroy Melbourne</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">06/05/2016</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">The Sunraysia Multicultural Festival</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Nowingi Place, Mildura Victoria</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have seemed to add dates into an array then sorted them - now I just too append them back to the body? Thanks

```
var dates = jQuery('tr.Entries').find('td.event-date > a').map(function() {
             return jQuery(this).text();
          }).get();
dates.sort(function(a,b){
var dateA = a;
dateA = dateA.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');
var dateB = b;
dateB = dateB.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');

return new Date(dateA).getTime() - new Date(dateB).getTime();
});
jQuery.each(dates, function (index, value) {
     //how to append back to tbody?
     console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: I have alot more rows but this is just a snippet

Comment: That's because `25/08/2017` is not a valid date to be parsed with `new Date`. [MDN: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so your `new Date` will all be an invalid Date. Is your date always formatted that way, or does it depend on the region of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date string is not in valid format. You can use `string#replace()` to change the date string to `MM-DD-YYYY` from `DD\MM\YYYY` and then covert to date and do the comparison.

```js
$('tr.Entries').sort(function(a,b){
  
 var dateA = jQuery(a).find('td.event-date > a').text();
 dateA = dateA.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');
 var dateB = jQuery(b).find('td.event-date > a').text();
 dateB = dateB.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');

 return new Date(dateB).getTime() - new Date(dateA).getTime();;

}).appendTo('tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="event clearfix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Event</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Ticket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">15/04/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Reggae, Seggae &amp; Sega Night</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Bar Open, Fitzroy Melbourne</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">06/05/2016</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">The Sunraysia Multicultural Festival</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Nowingi Place, Mildura Victoria</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">25/08/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Live N Local Winter Music Festival</a> 
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Pause Bar, Balaclava</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var dates = ['25/08/2017', '09/09/2017', '15/09/2017', '16/09/2017', '28/09/2017', '10/12/2017', '10/02/2018', '16/12/2017'];

dates.sort(function(a,b){
 var dateA = a;
 dateA = dateA.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');
 var dateB = b;
 dateB = dateB.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');

 return new Date(dateA).getTime() - new Date(dateB).getTime();
});
           
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: Hi your code works great for the first few entries, but I am not sure if it accounts for the year then when it hits 2018 it then goes back to 2017 - see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/sWABS

Comment: Hi I have updated the solution. I have also added a new code snippet based the image. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a go, but will have to autopopulate array from the dates column how is best to do this? each() statement?

Comment: Yeah, `each` could be one of the option. BTW, how are you getting the data?

Comment: This is a wordpress website

Comment: Hi Hassan I have updated my answer and have used your sort code - ty. i just need to append it back to the body?

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` doesn't know how to parse dates that have the day in the first section as opposed to the section. `Date` requires the format `MM/DD/YYYY`

If you take your first date `25/08/2017` and pass it into `new Date()` you will get an `Invalid Date` response.

If you want this to work you'll need to make sure the date is formatted into something `Date` understands so you can either do a swap programmatically or you can also pass in the parameters manually into the [`new Date` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)