# AppendTo tbody after sort() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, append

Hi I would like to append tr/td data back to tbody in a table after I have done a sort of table row - table cell dates from a dynamically populated list.

This follows on from my question here: [JavaScript Sort by Date on table not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519894/javascript-sort-by-date-on-table-not-working) where I have successfully sorted dates.

Thanks

```
var dates = jQuery('tr.Entries').find('td.event-date > a').map(function() {
             return jQuery(this).text();
          }).get();
dates.sort(function(a,b){
var dateA = a;
dateA = dateA.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');
var dateB = b;
dateB = dateB.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$2-$1-$3');

return new Date(dateA).getTime() - new Date(dateB).getTime();
});
jQuery.each(dates, function (index, value) {
     //how to append back to tbody?
     console.log(value);
});
```

Here are some entries (there are alot more - dynamically populated rows)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table class="event clearfix">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Event</td>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>Ticket</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="space"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">25/08/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Live N Local Winter Music Festival</a> 
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Pause Bar, Balaclava</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">15/04/2017</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">Reggae, Seggae &amp; Sega Night</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Bar Open, Fitzroy Melbourne</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date">
        <a href="#">06/05/2016</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-title">
        <a href="#">The Sunraysia Multicultural Festival</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-location">
        <a href="#">Nowingi Place, Mildura Victoria</a>
      </td>
      <td class="event-ticket-link">
        <a href="#" class="button button-normal">BUY TICKET</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not an experimented js user, but if they're not so many entries, i would just drop them all and append them back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the rows directly instead of the dates.
You can then pass the sorted rows to `.append()` and jQuery will add them all "at once".

```js
var dateRx = /(..)\/(..)\/(....)/,
  replaceFormat = "$2-$1-$3",
  rows = jQuery('tr.Entries')
          .get()
          .sort(function(rowA, rowB) {
            var dateA = $(rowA).find("td:first a").text().replace(dateRx, replaceFormat),
                dateB = $(rowB).find("td:first a").text().replace(dateRx, replaceFormat);

            return new Date(dateA) - new Date(dateB);
          });

jQuery("table.event tbody").append(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table class="event clearfix">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Date</td><td>Event</td></tr>
    <tr class="space"></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date"><a href="#">25/08/2017</a></td>
      <td class="event-title"><a href="#">Live N Local Winter Music Festival</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date"><a href="#">15/04/2017</a></td>
      <td class="event-title"><a href="#">Reggae, Seggae &amp; Sega Night</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Entries">
      <td class="event-date"><a href="#">06/05/2016</a></td>
      <td class="event-title"><a href="#">The Sunraysia Multicultural Festival</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

- Assign an `id` attribute to `<tbody>`
- before the `jQuery.each()` loop i would use [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to delete all `<tr>` entries from `<tbody>`
- inside the loop i would use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add back again sorted elements to `<tbody>` identiefied by `id` attribute

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have accepted Andreas answer.